# How to create two level circular progress indicator?

Tags: dart, flutter

Following is what i want to achieve

[image]

I was having a look at the Circular Percent Indicator library but that does not provide this functionality

The following is achieve in native Android Development
https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

but how to port it to Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by using a `stack` widget, it will allow you to place both indicators on an identical position which will get the effect of overlapping done :

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: 0.8,
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.purple),
    ),
    CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: 0.6,
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
    ),
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want the same progress bar to have two colors as well as a different background color

Comment: There's no easy path.

Comment: I have find a Native Android Solution but not sure how to port it to Flutter https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
[percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) library,

```
        new CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 130.0,
                animation: true,
                animationDuration: 1200,
                lineWidth: 15.0,
                percent: 0.4,
                center: Center(
                       child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                        ),
                circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                progressColor: Colors.green,
              ),
```